# Jsoup POST unable to login

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I am working around it for whole day and night and it just unable to login, I am giving up so I take the last chance here.

Here is the website that I wish to login: https://unitreg.utar.edu.my/portal/courseRegStu/login.jsp

And this is my POST code

```
Connection.Response oc = Jsoup.connect("https://unitreg.utar.edu.my/portal/courseRegStu/loginPro.jsp")
                        .data("preKap", mpreCap,"reqFregkey", mEmail,"reqPassword", mPassword,"kaptchafield", mCaptcha)
                        .cookie("JSESSIONID", SessID)
                        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                        .execute();
```

To verify, when you logged in into it, and you open a new tab and paste the login link on it, it will prompt HTML header "The website cannot display the page"

```
Document document1 =     Jsoup.connect("https://unitreg.utar.edu.my/portal/courseRegStu/login.jsp")
                        .cookie("JSESSIONID", SessID)
                        .get();

                Log.d("WTF", document1.toString());
                if (document1.title().contains("Welcome to Course Registration System")){
                    Log.d("HERE","Fail!");
```

Please help if you can, I am exhausted...

Comment: May I ask how you are retrieving `mCaptcha`? Because captcha functinoallity is there to explicitly prevent you from logging in automatically using code...

Comment: @JoelMin Hi, thanks for the reply. Firstly I start a connection to the login url to store the session. Then I parse out the Captcha url and put it into WebView so user can enter the captcha on client side. Soon I realize something which the Captcha changes every time I hit the refresh button even the captcha URL is still the same. Secondly, I realize that the Captcha url is generated using Unix Time http://unitreg.utar.edu.my/portal/Kaptcha.jpg?tmp=1464863494459 "1464863494459" is the time.